# One Google Maps Key for multiple developers (Android)? Eclipse custom keystore?

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

This cannot be impossible: We have four developers on an android app that uses the google maps api. We have generated a maps key that works for the one who generated it. All the others, however, see a tiled MapView without the actual map. Since my debug.keystore was used to generate, I was suspecting that the others need the same keystore. So I moved it into the repository so that everyone has a copy of it now. Then, everyone pointed eclipse towards that keystore using the custom keystore setting in Android->Build. This still does not work. What do we have to do? Surely we don't have to each use our own key and keep replacing it after every pull?

This site (and the web in general) contains tons of information on Google Maps API keys, but none answered my question unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps you could have two developers build the same sources, dump the apk's using an unzip tool and diff the results.  See what if anything is different, especially anything you would expect to be deterministic and independent of build time.  You might also try the same with an apk decompiler such as apktool

Comment: The way you're doing it should work as well as CommonsWares.

Comment: By "the way you are doing it" you mean copying the file into the project folder, and changing the path to custom debug.keystore in eclipse? I will try again then. I will also try the replacing the debug.keystore in the usual location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than trying to point Eclipse to a different keystore, just replace your local `debug.keystore` with the shared copy.

Comment: Great, this works for us now. We first had some trouble, most likely because we missed to recompile after we replaced the debug.keystore, but now it seems to work. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

In year 2013 for V2 you can include as many keystores app as you like. For me it was debug and production keystores. Just follow process described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) (this is a common process). When you create Android Key in Google API Console specify each fingerprint;package.name per line. E.g.:

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example
94:66:06:01:12:27:AC:39:BB:44:90:41:40:86:88:3D:96:A7:99:A9;com.example
```

That's it! Now you have 1 API Key for 2 keystores.

Answer (score 0):

In https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=IT, where your app is registered and where one of the teammates has created the key for the first time, first of all you have to go to your project. Then select your key and, between the options of the key, choose "No restrictions". Now you all can see Google maps in the app working.